# How to do conditional formatting on multiple columns, each based on its own values

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have a sheet with many columns, and I want to conditionally highlight each one with green for the top 25% of values (values > Q3), yellow for values between the top 25% and top 75% (values between Q1 and Q3) and red for the bottom 25% (values < Q1). I can do this for one column by using "Top/Bottom Rules", but is there a way to all the columns at once?

For example, I have the following data:

[image: no formatting]

I want for the formatting to look like this, where each column's formatting depends on its own quartile information:

[image]

Is there a way to do this without having to manually do each column on its own?

Answer (score 1):

I have found how to do this [here](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/copy-paste-conditional-formatting-excel-54266.html).
The way I did it for Excel 2019:

First, create the rules you want to condition your data with. In my case, this was done using `Conditional Formatting > Manage Rules > New Rule > Format cells that only contain`. Then, in the rule, I used the computed `Q1` and `Q3` to create the rules. I assume it is possible to do this using the `Use formula to determine which cells to format` and have the quartile formula in it. I am unsure if having `$` in the cell locations matters, I did it without the `$` in front of the letter (eg. `A$1`).

After creating the rules, select the column you created the rule on, then go to `Home` and click on `Format Painter` (located by default on the left in the `Clipboard` section, next to the `Paste`, `Cut` and `Copy`). After clicking on `Format Painter`, select the cells you want to apply the rules to.

Hope this helps anyone that has the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

@anInputName,
In order to avoid performing multiple operations for each column, I also suggest you `Use a formula to determine which cells to format`, maybe you could try the following formula to format the cells.

```
=B2>B$17
=B2<B$16
=AND(B2>=B$16,B2<=B$17)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! What I have done is essentially the same thing, you can check the rules set I am using [here](https://i.gyazo.com/1f6e9ec0c0825649713393bf1f8b85f9.png). Basically the same thing, but using Excel's built in "greater than", "less than" and "between".

Comment: OK, hope to have a nice week~